# Hit two pythons with one computer

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, development-environment

How would one set up python 2.7 and python 3.x on the same computer. Most of my old code is in 2, but a platform I am trying to use uses 3. How do I setup an enviroment in which I can work on both easily. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 by the way, so no Windows exclusives.

Comment: Install them both and configure the appropriate executable to each project in your IDE. Alternatively create two virtualenvs, and you'll be set

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much said it in your question. You need to setup *an environment*, a [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to be precise. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1534343/276451 it's exactly what you're looking for.